# Haskell foldr reduction

Tags: haskell, lambda, fold, reduction

I am still very new to Haskell and I am trying to solve a problem. I have attempted something but I am very sure it is wrong.

**The Problem:**

```
foldr : f x NIL = x
foldr : f x (cons a list) = f a (foldr f x list)
```

Let’s have some fun and combine the features of a number of different languages.

(1) Borrowing from the course notes and Haskell, let’s define a function foldl,

(a) `foldl f x NIL = x`

(b) `foldl f x (cons a list) = foldl f (f x a) list`

(2) Borrowing from Python, we can treat a string as a sequence (i.e. a list) of characters,

```
“bar” ≡ (‘b’ ‘a’ ‘r’) ≡ [‘b’, ‘a’, ‘r’]
```

(3) Borrowing from Lisp, we can use cons cells to represent or create lists,

```
(‘b’ ‘a’ ‘r’) ≡ (cons ‘b’ (cons ‘a’ (cons ‘r’ nil)))
```

(4) Borrowing from Fortran, we can define a string concatenation function, //,

```
‘concate’//’nation’ ⇒‘concatenation’
```

(5) Borrowing from Scheme, define a toggle function,

```
f x y = f y x,
(define toggle (lambda (f x y)  (f y x)))
```

That is, the toggle function switches its arguments, in Lambda Calculus, it’s,

```
|_f. |_x. |_y. f y x
```

Thus, for example,

```
(f ‘back’ ‘drop’) ⇒(f ‘drop’ back’)
```

**In this question, please trace the execution/reduction of the following function:**

```
foldl (toggle //) nil (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
```

**Below is a Hint I am Given:**

```
    foldl (toggle //) nil (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
```

Step1: Start with (1b), left side, `foldl f x (cons a list)`

```
        with f = (toggle //), x = nil, and list = (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
```

Step2: Use (3) to recursively expand the list

Step3: Use (1b), right-side, foldl f (f x a) list

```
        to recursively apply f, (toggle //), to the expanded list
```

Step4: Use (5) to apply the toggle functions in the list expression.

Step5: Use (4), //, to reduce the expression

**What I Got:**

```
foldl (toggle //) nil (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
foldl f x (cons a list) – via (1b)
foldl f x(a list)  – via (3)
foldl f (f x a) list – via (1b)
foldl (toggle //) (toggle // x a) list – via(5)
foldl x // // a list – via (4)
foldl nil a (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
```

I know that can't be right but I feel like I am somewhere near. If I could get some guidance I feel I could become unstuck and have a successful understanding.

Comment: stick with Haskell's syntax (equations, `[...]`, ...) when you're working it out; it's the clearest. then when you're done, translate the results back to whatever crazy mix of notations is expected of you.

Answer (score 2):

start with

```
foldl (toggle //) nil (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
{ 1b }
= foldl (toggle //) ((toggle //) nil "foo") (“bar” “baz”)
```

...

### remarks/questions:

- `("foo" "bar" "baz")` is not Haskell for lists! (what are the strange `"`?)
- `(toggle //)` is not Haskell syntax for operators either (it's `(toggle (//))`)
- what strategy are you supposed to use? Depending on it you have to continue with the `(toggle //) nil "foo")` or the `foldl`

the `toggle` would be

```
(toggle //) nil "foo"
{ 5 }
= (//) "foo" nil
{ 4 }
"foo"
```

the other would be the same again:

```
foldl (toggle //) ((toggle //) nil "foo") (“bar” “baz”)
{ 1b }
= foldl (toggle //) ((toggle //) ((toggle //) nil "foo") "bar") ("baz")
```

I'm sure you can work out the rest (it's really just putting the right thing into the right *spot* )

Comment: `(toggle //)` is valid syntax — it is like `(1 +)` — but it is a type error, so I think you're probably correct that `(toggle (//))` was meant.

Comment: How are you getting: **foldl (toggle //) nil (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
{ 1b }
= foldl (toggle //) ((toggle //) nil "foo") (“bar” “baz”)**? I don't see how you get that from 1b.

Comment: do you see it if I say you that `(cons "foo" ("bar" "baz")) = ("foo" "bar" "baz")` (modulo syntax - as I said it's not Haskell - but `cons` in LISP is `(:)` in Haskell and if you say `a:b:c:[] = [a,b,c] = (a b c) = (cons a (b c))` then it should hold

Comment: @Carsten Ok. I'm confused how the toggle actually works then. For **foldl (toggle //) ((toggle //) ((toggle //) nil "foo") "bar") ("baz")**, what does toggle actually do? I thought it switched the position of the next to elements to the right. After one step would it be: **foldl (toggle //) (toggle //) ("foo" nil) "bar") ("baz")**

Comment: no think of it as having one argument - a function - here `(//)` - it will take this and return a new function which will just use the one given but *flip* the arguments - so if you do `(toggle (//)) a b` it will be the same as `(//) b a` which is `b // a` or `b ++ a` in Haskell

Comment: but IMO the exercise is given in a horrible fashion as you are expected to understand and mix the syntax of various languages - so no surprise you've got issues with this

Comment: in Haskell you would (as the other answer implies) `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)`  with `flip f a b = f b a` which you could write as `flip f = \ a b -> f b a` to make it more obvious

Comment: @Carsten That makes sense. I seem to understand the basics, but you are right, this is a poorly formatted question. I don't think I will understand it enough to answer the question successfully, although I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is replace all the alien syntax and names with Haskell syntax and names.

```
toggle              ⇒ flip
nil                 ⇒ []
(“foo” “bar” “baz”) ⇒ ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
(//)                ⇒ (++)
```

Giving:

```
foldl (toggle (//)) nil (“foo” “bar” “baz”)
⇒ foldl (flip (++)) [] ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

> **Note:** I am correcting `(toggle //)` to `(toggle (//))` because I think the latter is what was intended. The former is a type error.

Now you just expand the definition of `foldl`. Again I would replace the alien syntax and names with Haskell syntax and names.

```
foldl f x NIL = x
foldl f x (cons a list) = foldl f (f x a) list
```

Becomes:

```
foldl f a [] = a
foldl f a (x:xs) = foldl f (f a x) xs
```

Now you apply `foldl` to its arguments. There are are a couple things you can do. One thing is to rewrite `foldl` so it is an expression.

```
foldl =
  \f -> \a -> \xxs ->
    case xxs of
      []   -> a
      x:xs -> foldl f (f a x) xs
```

Or on one line as:

```
foldl = \f -> \a -> \xxs -> case xxs of [] -> a; x:xs -> foldl f (f a x) xs
```

You can also desugar the list `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` to `"foo":"bar":"baz":[]`, which makes pattern matching more obvious.

Now expand `foldl` and apply:

```
foldl (flip (++)) [] ("foo":"bar":"baz":[])
⇒ (\f -> \a -> \xxs -> case xxs of [] -> a; x:xs -> foldl f (f a x) xs) (flip (++)) [] ("foo":"bar":"baz":[])
⇒ (\a -> \xxs -> case xxs of [] -> a; x:xs -> foldl (flip (++)) ((flip (++)) a x) xs) [] ("foo":"bar":"baz":[])
⇒ (\xxs -> case xxs of [] -> []; x:xs -> foldl (flip (++)) ((flip (++)) [] x) xs) ("foo":"bar":"baz":[])
⇒ case "foo":"bar":"baz":[] of [] -> []; x:xs -> foldl (flip (++)) ((flip (++)) [] x) xs
```

Simplify the case expression:

```
case ("foo":"bar":"baz":[]) of [] -> []; x:xs -> foldl (flip (++)) ((flip (++)) [] x) xs
⇒ foldl (flip (++)) ((flip (++)) [] "foo") ("bar":"baz":[])
```

You can finish the normalisation in the same manner.

Once you understand that a function definition such as `foldl` is really just sugar on a case expression you can take a shortcut.

> **Note:** There are other rich syntaxes such as guards and do-notation. When you want to evaluate them it will help to know the underlying expression.

Starting from:

```
foldl (flip (++)) [] ("foo":"bar":"baz":[])
```

We can look at this definition of `foldl`:

```
foldl f a [] = a
foldl f a (x:xs) = foldl f (f a x) xs
```

And immediately choose either the `a` definition or the `foldl f (f a x) xs` definition based which case matches. In this case it is the latter. Having chosen the correct definition we substitute all the parameters for arguments and quickly arrive at the same expression as before:

```
foldl (flip (++)) ((flip (++)) [] "foo") ("bar":"baz":[])
```

You can see that my general approach has been to simplify the syntax. That is, simpler to manipulate rather than simpler to read or write, which usually means reducing to fewer primitives. We managed with just using `case`, abstraction (i.e. `\x -> m`), and application (i.e. `f x`, substituting parameters for arguments). This is a good approach if the rules of how to use the richer syntax (or in the case of this problem, invented syntax) are not clear.